# Repeating modal content in printing mode

Tags: bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I have issue with ng-bootstrap and latest Firefox
When i`m print page in portrait mode with opened modal window, modal content cloning into 2 page

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

[image: clone]

May be someone known why it happen?

Answer (score 0):

i fix this problem by this css rule

```
@media print {
    .modal-open .wrapper {
        display: none;
    }
}
```