# How to prevent window.print() from generating 2 outputs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have the following minimal reproducible code: https://jsfiddle.net/nay23vph/

On invocation of `window.print()`, the output seems to be generating 2 tables instead of 1. I referred to the following solution but could neither understand what the issue is, nor implement it on my code : [window.print() repeating modal on every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60810643/window-print-repeating-modal-on-every-page)

Here is my css blocks for print div:

```
@page {

    size: 3in 2in;
    margin: 0mm;
}

@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      .printDiv, .printDiv * {
        visibility: visible;
      }
      .printDiv {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      .printDiv{
        background-color: rgb(5, 3, 3);
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed; 
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 11px;
        border: 11px solid #000000;
        
    }
}
```

Here is the div to be printed:

```
<div class = "item item-content item-content-title print-form printDiv">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>                        
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>DataDataDataData</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataDataDataData</td>
            <td>DataDataDataData</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any suggestion or help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I get only one copy. Are you certain your printer setup isn’t set to two copies?

Comment: Hey @AHaworth, I am referring to pages in the question, not copies. The issue isn't related to the printer as the print dialogue page generates 2 duplicate pages as well.